# iOS: FTP TLS Connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ftp, ios, inputstream

I need a FTP TLS Connection for my iPhone-App. A normal FTP-Connection works fine. But I need also a secure TLS connection.
I used the code from Apple´s SimpleFTPSample for the iPhone:

```
ftpStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (CFURLRef) url);
self.networkStream = (NSInputStream *) ftpStream;

[self.networkStream retain];
self.networkStream.delegate = self;


CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)self.networkStream, kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName, (CFStringRef)@"ftpuser");
CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)self.networkStream, kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword, (CFStringRef)myFTPPassWord);


[self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.networkStream open];
```

This works fine for a normal FTP Connection.

But how do I setup a TLS Connection?
I´m not sure what I need and if a TLS Connection works?

I tried some code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:5];
[settings setObject:(NSString *)NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1 forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLLevel];
[settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot];
CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)self.networkStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)settings);
```

But without any success. Please can somebody help me.
I need a FTP TLS Connection which is protected with a FTP Username and FTP Password.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you say "FTP TLS" I assume you mean RFC 4217? I'm fairly certain that CFStream doesn't support that protocol. You'll have to build it up yourself. You may want to look at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) as a good solution. I've been reasonably happy with it for managing TFTP.

Comment: can you share how to build libcurl on IOS? i have follow the steps in http://www.intelliproject.net/articles/showArticle/index/use_curl_iphone_sdk and http://www.creativealgorithms.com/blog/content/building-libcurl-ios-42#comment-3262, but when i try to build on xcode, it gives me thousands errors, can you help me?

Comment: I haven't done it in a long time, but this link looks pretty similar to the procedure I've used: http://www.creativealgorithms.com/blog/content/building-libcurl-ios-42